# Violation: 'submit' handler took 1515ms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools

[image]

I am building a registration form using react and got this warning. I am not getting from where and why this error is coming. Because of this warning, I am unable to see my form data in the console.